# JavaScript prototype inside "Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am writing functions inside Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE).

```
(function(){
  "use strict";
  function EventService(){
    //MASTER CLASS
  }
  EventService.prototype.eventObj = function(){
    var ES = getEvwentMapping();
    return EventService;
  };
  EventService.prototype.popup = function(){
    eventService.eventObj.createPopup();
  };
  EventService.prototype.drilldown = function(){
    eventService.eventObj.createDrilldown();
  };
})();


eventService();
```

Here I am getting error as **eventService()** is undefined.

Comment: Yes. your function is not available in the global scope.

Comment: add `window.eventService = eventService;` in `(function(window){   })(window);`

Comment: Why do you think you need an IIFE here anyway? You IIFE doesn't actual execute anything anyway.

Comment: Your code is not correct. You can not call the createPopup of something that is not defined; the eventService.eventObj evaluates to undefined. What you probably want to do is eventService.prototype.eventObj() which again is not the best solution. A better way is to call this.eventObj().createPopup()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your function is enclosed in your IIFE and doesn't become part of any external scope. If you need it outside your function, then try returning it and assigning it to a variable. For example:

```
var eventService = (function(){
    "use strict";
    function eventService(){
         //MASTER CLASS
    }
    eventService.prototype.eventObj = function(){
        var ES = getEvwentMapping();
        return EventService;
    };
    eventService.prototype.popup = function(){
        eventService.eventObj.createPopup();
    };
    eventService.prototype.drilldown = function(){
        eventService.eventObj.createDrilldown();
    };
    return eventService;
})();
```

Or the module patern suggested by @ppoliani is also good if you have several functions and/or properties you need to expose.

Another question, however, is why you think you need an IIFE here anyway? This would work the same by just removing the IIFE altogether.

Here's how you'd use the thing:

```
var myES = new eventService();
myES.popup();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7ZJY/

EDIT: As I said before, there is no reason to actually use an IIFE here because you aren't hiding anything and you code doesn't actual execute anything anyway. But, one way you might use this is to create a singleton and I'm wondering if that was your actual objective here. What you could do is this:

```
var eventServiceSingleton = (function(){
    "use strict";
    function eventService(){
         //MASTER CLASS
    }
    eventService.prototype.eventObj = function(){
        var ES = getEvwentMapping();
        return EventService;
    };
    eventService.prototype.popup = function(){
        eventService.eventObj.createPopup();
    };
    eventService.prototype.drilldown = function(){
        eventService.eventObj.createDrilldown();
    };
    return new eventService();
})();
```

Now you have a fully constructed `eventService` assigned to the variable `eventServiceSingleton` and there is no way to create another `eventService` object. So now:

```
 eventServiceSingleton.popup();   // works
```

but:

```
 var anotherEventService = new eventService();    // eventService is undefined
```

Comment: I am getting error as eventService.popup(); is not a a function

Comment: You need to create your `eventService` with the `new` keyword.

Comment: The code above has some errors. First of all we need to change eventService.eventObj into eventService.prototype.eventObj() or even better this.eventObj()

Comment: @ppoliani: Probably true, but I wasn't about to try and guess at what the OP actually wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply the module pattern which returns a constructor.

```
var EventService = (function(){

   "use strict";

   function EventService(){
    //MASTER CLASS
   }

   EventService.prototype.eventObj = function(){
     var ES = getEvwentMapping();
     return ES;
   };

  EventService.prototype.popup = function(){
    this.eventObj().createPopup();
  };

  EventService.prototype.drilldown = function(){
    this.eventObj().createDrilldown();
  };

  return EventService;
})();
```

and then you can simply invoke the method by doing

```
var eventService = new EventService();
eventService.popup();
```

The issue is that you are trying to apply a sort of encapsulation with the aid of JavaScript closures; that is anything defined within the closure is not accessible from the outside unless you explicitly export them.

However, you're definitely doing something wrong here; As @Matt Burland mentioned, you don't need to use an IIFE here. You can benefit from a IIFE when you want to conceal some variables so that you don't pollute the global scope or you simply don't want to make them accessible. I cannot see that intention in your code.

Comment: I am getting error as service.eventService.popup(); is noa a function

Comment: @ppoliani You should not edit the question with code correction!

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for using IIFE is because you want to leave a minimal footprint -- no unnecessary variables left behind.

if you only want to invoke eventService once, then you just need to invoke eventService at the end of your IIFE.

```
(function(){
  "use strict";
  function eventService(){
    //MASTER CLASS
  }
  eventService.prototype.eventObj = function(){
    var ES = getEventMapping();
    return eventService;
  };
  eventService.prototype.popup = function(){
    eventService.eventObj.createPopup();
  };
  eventService.prototype.drilldown = function(){
    eventService.eventObj.createDrilldown();
  };
  eventService(); // This is all you need to invoke just once
})();
```

However, if you want to save a reference to the eventService function to invoke it more than once, then that needs to be the return value of your IIFE.

```
var eventService = (function(){
  "use strict";
  function eventService(){
    //MASTER CLASS
  }
  eventService.prototype.eventObj = function(){
    var ES = getEventMapping();
    return eventService;
  };
  eventService.prototype.popup = function(){
    eventService.eventObj.createPopup();
  };
  eventService.prototype.drilldown = function(){
    eventService.eventObj.createDrilldown();
  };
  return eventService; // return the function for future invocations
})();

eventService();
```

Comment: I want to make it as second option but whenever I try to call internal functions of event service like eventService.popup() or  eventService.drilldown() I am getting error as eventService.popup() is undefined

Comment: @Anup-singh, your original code has errors. However, the reason you're getting "eventService.popup()" is undefined is that you need to create your instance with a `new` call.

    `var es = eventService();
    es.popup();`